# Create .wmv file from flash files

Tags: flash, wmv

Is it possible to convert flash files like .fla or .swf to .wmv(windows media video format)? Or is it possible to somehow generate .wmv file from flash files?

Answer (score 0):

You can use programs like sothink video converter.

http://www.sothink.com/product/swftovideoconverter/